# Why do my mouse's cordinates appear somewhere else than the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im trying to make so when you click on a canvas, there comes a circle at the mouse's cordinates.
When i click the canvas the circle appears maybe 300 pixels to low.

I tried changing from pageX/Y, clientX/Y and screenX/Y.

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="300px" height="200px" style="border: 1px solid #000; Padding-bottom: 100px;">
</canvas>
<script>
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            addEventListener("mousedown", drawCircle)
        }

        function drawCircle(event) 
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            x = event.pageX
            y = event.pageY

            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill()
        } 
</script>
```

I expect the circle to appear at the mouse's cordinates.

Comment: I just put this in a jsfiddle and the circles showed up where i clicked.

Comment: If your canvas is below the top of your document, it will push the circles down.

Comment: So i can have no header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly being offset by other elements on the page around the canvas. Try something like this to get x/y relative to canvas:

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 200;
    addEventListener("mousedown", drawCircle)
  }

  function drawCircle(event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = (event.clientX - rect.left)
    y = (event.clientY - rect.top)

    //x = event.pageX
    //y = event.pageY

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill()
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: using `offsetX` or `offsetY` does this calculation for you natively.

Comment: offsetX/Y probably better and cleaner but you'll need to change the mousedown eventlistener to be on the canvas specifically, rather than the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the position of the canvas itself. it looks like your code assumes the canvas is always in the top left of the screen.

There is also some issues with your canvas element. The width and height should just be numbers (no "px" required). The bottom padding is making the bottom half of the canvas inaccessible.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  addEventListener("mousedown", drawCircle)
}

function drawCircle(event) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="300" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1z5modk2/1/

Instead of using `pageX` and `pageY`, use `offsetX` and `offsetY`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX